# Power/sleep button doesn't do anything

Tags: windows-7, laptop

Power button doesn't put the laptop to sleep or turns it off - in fact, it does nothing, redgardless if the laptop is connected to power or not. I have a ThinkPad T410s, and these are my power settings:

[image]

Comment: Is this a new laptop?  Has it ever worked properly?  Have you tried changing the behavior of the power button?  Does the sleep button perform correctly?

Comment: Did you try keeping the button pressed for a minute or so? It should bypass operating system and immediately shut down the computer. If that doesn't work, it could be a hardware problem.

Comment: New laptop, I tweaked the power settings a bit before checking this. I don't want to shutdown it completely, but I imagine it would work. What I'd like is the "clean shutdown" or sleep functionality. Going to try to shutdown now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, when I pressed it for about half a second this did the trick (sleep, just like I configured it). I'm simply used to even shorter clicks activating the sleep/shutdown, and in this model it takes a bit longer.